# JPA Where Exists/Join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join

i have a problem with a jpa query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Product p INNER JOIN p.shopCategories sc WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT sc2 FROM Customer c INNER JOIN c.shopCategories as sc2 WHERE c.customerId=7)
```

The result should be only pages which have a shop categories where the customer has booked that shop category.

Product <-> ShopCategory <-> Customer

But the result is a list with all products for which any ShopCategory exists.

Any ideas how to improve the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just join all the way to customer

```
SELECT DISTINCT p 
FROM Product p 
   INNER JOIN p.shopCategories sc
   INNER JOIN sc.customer c
WHERE c.customerId = 7
```

If you have bi-directional mappings in your ShopCategories entity of course.

**Update**

Using the EXISTS, i think you need to correlate the inner query with the parent one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Product p INNER JOIN p.shopCategories sc 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT sc2 FROM Customer c INNER JOIN c.shopCategories as sc2 WHERE c.customerId=7 and sc = sc2)
```

Comment: Sadly there is no bi-directional relation. Any other idea?